# Struts 2 Custom Tag Library

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, struts2

I created a custom tag library for my struts 2 project. Now I want to put all my source code into a jar file. It's working fine but my concern is I still need to configure my .tld file in the web xml for it to work:

```
<jsp-config>
    <taglib>
        <taglib-uri>/custom-tags</taglib-uri>
        <taglib-location>/META-INF/mytaglib.tld</taglib-location>
    </taglib>
</jsp-config>
```

Is there a way to get rid of this and configuring it in the jar file instead?

Answer (score 1):

This shouldn't have anything to do with Struts2, really.  To get away from configuring this in the web.xml, you should just be able to place your .tld file into a META-INF folder at the root of your jar and declare the uri inside the .tld using `<uri>/custom-tags</uri>`.